# Allocating memory for a texture

Tags: graphics, directx, direct3d

I've been looking at the WICTextureLoader.cpp file that is part of the DirectX Toolkit. And I'm trying to understand this bit of code:

https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/WICTextureLoader.cpp#L530

```
   // Allocate temporary memory for image
   uint64_t rowBytes = (uint64_t(twidth) * uint64_t(bpp) + 7u) / 8u;
   uint64_t numBytes = rowBytes * uint64_t(theight);
```

I understand that you'd need to allocate the texture width * bits per pixel for a single row of the texture. But I do not understand the addition of 7 per pixel and then the division of the whole thing by 8. What is that about?

Comment: It makes sure rowBytes is divisible by 8 and can contain twidth * bpp.

Comment: @SimonMourier OK thank you. But why would it be important that the space allocated in system memory for pixel data be a multiple of 8?

Comment: This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicbitmapsource-copypixels#codec-developer-remarks the pitch/stride is aligned on some boundary (4, 8, etc), this is the reason why it even exists: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/image-stride

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you. Also I guess since they are doing bits per pixel rather than bytes I suppose it also would be necessary since you can't allocate less than a byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bpp` here is "bits per pixel". The expression rounds **up** to the next whole byte (8 bits).

This is a classic C pattern for "align up" for power-of-2 alignments, here expressed as a C++ template.

```
    template<typename T>
    inline T AlignUp(T size, size_t alignment) noexcept
    {
        if (alignment > 0)
        {
            assert(((alignment - 1) & alignment) == 0);
            auto mask = static_cast<T>(alignment - 1);
            return (size + mask) & ~mask;
        }
        return size;
    }
```

Instead of `/ 8`, I could have used bit operators (again, since it's a power of two) and done `& ~8` but the `/ 8` seems clearer.